# Using lambdas' unique types to merge duplicates in a compile time list of variables?

Tags: c++, lambda, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to make an algebraic data type library for doing relational logic in C++.  I need to capture the list of variables in a logic expression as part of the type of a logic expression.  (This is analogous to how the parameter list of a function is part of the function's type.)

(When I say "a variable" in this question, I mean a logic variable, which is an object of a template class defined by the library.  It comes equipped with overloaded operators whose template functions' return types encode information about the variables involved in the expression.)

```
e : Expr<T,U,V,...> means e is a relation over variables T, U, V, ...
```

When two relations are combined with a binary operator (e.g. && or ||), the type list should grow to include the union of the variables from both sides.  However, if the *same variable* is reused on both sides, it should only count once in the final set.

The combination of two relations of one variable is a relation on two variables:

```
expr(t) && expr(u) -> Expr<T,U>, given t:T and u:U
```

Unless it is really the same variable, in which case its still a relation over one variable:

```
expr1(t) && expr2(t) -> Expr<T>, given t:T
```

...with the obvious extension to cases of more than two variables.

However note the difference between a variable being *of the same type (of values)*  versus being *the same* variable.  We do not want to collapse different variables that represent values of the same type, only reuses of the same variable.

In order to do this, we have to be able to associate some means of ID with a particular variable which can be incorporated into a template type.

I can think of three solutions:

1. Make variables unique with an **`int`** template argument. (For
   instance `__LINE__` or `__COUNTER__` might work.)
2. Use a constexpr address of something as a template argument.  (Does not work on local variables.)
3. Generate types that are directly unique using lambdas.

The problem with #1 is that variables created in different source files might incorrectly receive the same int value.  The problem with #2 is that it requires something static/global such as a global variable or the address of a (regular) function.  That makes it inconvenient to create relation expressions in local scopes.

That leaves lambdas.  It seems from the standards wording it is guaranteed every lambda expression is a unique type.  (?)  Furthermore they are easy to create in local scopes.  Even the fact that a variable created in a function has a type that is "unspeakable" outside the function scope is something I consider a feature-rather-than-a-bug, because my main intent is to get automatic tracking of well-typed-ness within an expression or function.  I expect the user to cast/convert the relation to a simpler signature when they return it.

(The biggest problem I can see is with recursion; different instances of the variable on different stack frames would incorrectly be seen as the same.  Perhaps there could be a special type of variable that the ADT system knows not to try to merge.)

Anyway here's the rough idea.  Is this good/bad/clever/horrible?

```
template <typename T> 
struct Expr_of_1 {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Expr_of_2 {};

template <typename T>
auto lt(T, int) -> Expr_of_1<T> 
    { return Expr_of_1<T>(); }

template <typename T, typename U>
auto operator &&(Expr_of_1<T>, Expr_of_1<U>) -> Expr_of_2<T,U>
    { return Expr_of_2<T,U>(); }

template <typename T>
auto operator &&(Expr_of_1<T>, Expr_of_1<T>) -> Expr_of_1<T>
    { return Expr_of_1<T>(); }

template <typename T, typename U>
void takes_two(Expr_of_2<T,U>)
    {}

int main()
{
  auto var_x = [](){};
  auto var_y = [](){};
  auto expr_xy = lt(var_x, 5) && lt(var_y, 8);  // expr(x) && expr(y) -> expr(x,y)
  auto expr_xx = lt(var_x, 5) && lt(var_x, 8);  // expr(x) && expr(x) -> still expr(x)
  takes_two(expr_xy);  // OK
  //takes_two(expr_xx);  // Not allowed
  return 0;
};
```

Comment: Note that you may use local struct instead of lambda: `struct {} var_x;`.

Comment: Put that in an answer and I'll accept it!  I just tested it; you're right there's nothing special about using lambda for that, the `struct {} ident;` snippet you gave works just as well.  Now as for whether using it is a good *design* idea is still debateable.